# I have an embedded Google Map which includes a marker. This marker is lost when I click through to detailed map

Tags: google-maps

I have an embedded Google Map which includes a marker. The marker displays fine in the embedded map.

However when I click the "Google" logo in the bottom left corner of the embedded map, which takes me through to the map in the full Google Maps site, the marker is nowhere to be seen. How can I ensure that the marker is carried through to the detailed Google Map?

Map is generated as follows:

```
<div class="googlemap"><div id="mapDiv" class="googleMaps" style="width: 380px; height: 300px"><script>
      function tpinitmap() {
      var tpcoords = new google.maps.LatLng('13.704312','100.492296');
      var tpmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {scrollwheel:false, zoom: 14, center: tpcoords, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});
      var tpmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: tpcoords, map: tpmap, title: 'Anantara Bangkok Riverside Resort & Spa'});
      }
    </script><script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=tpinitmap"></script></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do as you have indicated. click on the logo of google links you to `google maps` and not to your application. Google Maps does not know your application and the script that was added in the application to display the marker.
If you want a larger map must enlarge the div of your map. for example like with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<head>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

```
    <div id="mapDiv" class="googleMaps" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>

        <script>
            function initialize() {
                var tpcoords = new google.maps.LatLng('13.704312','100.492296');
                var tpmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {scrollwheel:false, zoom: 14, center: tpcoords, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});
                var tpmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: tpcoords, map: tpmap, title: 'Anantara Bangkok Riverside Resort & Spa'});
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

To view the map in full screen make sure all tags parent containers of the map (html, body, ...., div of map) we have the size assigned to width: 100%; height: 100%;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I believe it is possible to configure your map so that the Google Logo link includes parameter(s) such that when clicked the marker is shown on the Google Maps web page. Take this for example from Google's own documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

If you click the "View Larger Map" link on the first embedded map show, the marker is retained on the newly opened web page. That's the effect I want to use on my map, but there aren't any clear instructions on how to do this in Google's own documentation.